# How to only restart node process with PM2 if exit code != 0

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to manage a node process. 
Currently, pm2 restarts the node process even if it finishes cleanly (with exit code 0). I don't want that to happen.

Instead I only want PM2 to restart the app when the node process exits with a code != 0.

How to do this?

The pm2 logs might be useful:

```
PM2        | App [xxx] with id [0] and pid [44797], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:xxx id:0
PM2        | App name:xxx id:0 online
```

**EDIT**:

Seems that starting process in cluster-mode works as I expect. I.e.: restarts only happen on exit-codes !=0.

Still starting in fork-mode gives the unexpected behavior as described above.

Comment: Are you sure? Because for me both work the same way. `setTimeout(()=>process.exit(), 2000);` and be it cluster mode or fork mode both restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late to this thread, but I believe pm2 support this now.  Check out https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/ and the section "Skip Auto Restart For Specific Exit Codes"

Edit: Sorry, this is not the solution yet.  There is an open issue related to this pm2 option here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5208.  From the looks of it I don't expect it to be resolved anytime soon.  So the above option *should* work but I don't think it does at the moment with the current version of pm2 as of this writing (5.1.12)

Comment: Although late, it's still the correct answer now :) Awesome

Answer (score 6):

I have looked at the code of `pm2`

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/6090b0971abca6fcb2d796e560f2a72b81ab5707/lib/God.js

And it doesn't seems to have any logic in terms of not starting a process on a successful exit. The feature you are asking for doesn't exists. It is same for cluster as well as fork mode.

You can test that using `test.js`

```
setTimeout(()=>process.exit(), 2000);
```

**Fork mode**

```sh
$ pm2 start test.js && sleep 5
[PM2] Starting /Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/pm2exit/test.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ user         │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────────┼──────────┤
│ test     │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 5889 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 9.4 MB   │ tarunlalwani │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
$ pm2 logs
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:23: PM2 log: App [test:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:23: PM2 log: App [test:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:23: PM2 log: App [test:0] online
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:25: PM2 log: App [test:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:25: PM2 log: App [test:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-08-18T11:40:25: PM2 log: App [test:0] online

$ pm2 delete test
```

```sh
$ pm2 start test.js -i 2&& sleep 5
[PM2] Starting /Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/pm2exit/test.js in cluster_mode (2 instances)
[PM2] Done.
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode    │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user         │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────────────┼──────────┤
│ test     │ 0  │ N/A     │ cluster │ 5993 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 27.6 MB   │ tarunlalwani │ disabled │
│ test     │ 1  │ N/A     │ cluster │ 5994 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 20.8 MB   │ tarunlalwani │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app

$ pm2 logs
PM2      | App name:test id:0 disconnected
PM2      | App [test:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [test:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2      | App name:test id:1 disconnected
PM2      | App [test:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [test:1] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2      | App [test:0] online
PM2      | App [test:1] online
PM2      | App name:test id:0 disconnected
PM2      | App [test:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [test:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2      | App name:test id:1 disconnected
PM2      | App [test:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [test:1] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2      | App [test:0] online
PM2      | App [test:1] online
PM2      | App name:test id:0 disconnected

$ pm2 delete test
```

**Alternative**

As an alternative you can use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

You can use the `exitcodes` in the configuration file

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

> The list of “expected” exit codes for this program used with `autorestart`. If the `autorestart` parameter is set to unexpected, and the process exits in any other way than as a result of a supervisor stop request, `supervisor`d will restart the process if it exits with an exit code that is not defined in this list.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but an authoritative one. I personally worked around the limitation by invoking PM2 API from my Node application to call for a stop instead of just exiting, but it's a poor workaround for many reasons. Any other similar tools that can support exit code logic?

Comment: @Xan, I updated the answer with the description of alternative as such

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the `stop_exit_codes` parameter.

See here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

According to their docs:

**CLI:**

```
pm2 start app.js --stop-exit-codes 0
```

**Via configuration file:**

```
module.exports = [{
  script: 'app.js',
  stop_exit_codes: [0]
}]
```

Answer (score -3):

Add the `--no-autorestart` option to `pm2 start`, or in your JSON configuration file.

Comment: This prevents pm2 from restarting even in case of error (i.e.: `code != 0`)

Comment: This is important and nice if you have any other monitoring tool that takes care of the restarting. Good for docker orchestration. Nice to know and have in that case.